# pass html multiselect picklist value to controller

Tags: visualforce, controller, html, multi-select

i have problem with passing multiselect picklist value to controller, and i want to insert it to picklist(multiselect) field.
what should i do to achieve this ?

here's my visualforce

```
<apex:inputHidden value="{!banks}" id="banksId"/> 
  <select multiple="multiple" onchange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.banksId}').value = this.value;">
        <option value="Standard Chartered;" >Standard Chartered</option> 
        <option value="ANZ;">ANZ</option> 
        <option value="DBS;">DBS</option> 
        <option value="UOB;">UOB</option> 
    </select>
```

here's my apex class

```
public PageReference Submit(){

public String[] banks{get;set;}
public String banks2SF{get;set;}
public PageReference Submit(){
if(banks.size()>0){
    for(Integer i=0;i<banks.size();i++){
         banks2SF +=banks[i]+';';
    }
}
web2lead.List_of_Bank__c = banks2SF;
update web2lead;
}
```

it didn't store the any values, **List_of_Bank__c is picklist(multiselect)** and it only accept string not an array string. i need use html `<select>` tag not `<apex:SelectList>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `this.value;` only pass the current selected value. I have added a JS function `getSelectValues` to assign all selected values to the hidden variable. Also you option values has semicolon present in it. I have removed them as comma is added as a separator with `push` function from JS. Hope this helps.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="MutiSelect">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSelectValues(select) {
            var result = [];
            var options = select && select.options;
            var opt;
            for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
                opt = options[i];
                if (opt.selected) {
                    result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }    
    </script>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!banks2SF}" id="banksId"/> 
        <select multiple="multiple" onchange="document.getElementById('{!$Component.banksId}').value = getSelectValues(this);">
            <option value="Standard Chartered;" >Standard Chartered</option> 
            <option value="ANZ">ANZ</option> 
            <option value="DBS">DBS</option> 
            <option value="UOB">UOB</option> 
        </select>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Submit}" value="Submit"/>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Controller

Now `banks2SF` is having all the values comma separated like `ANZ,DBS,UOB`. Now as per you code I have split it by comma and assign to the `banks`. The values of the banks can be seen in debug logs.

```
public class MutiSelect {
    public String[] banks{get;set;}
    public String banks2SF{get;set;}    
    public PageReference Submit(){
        system.debug('++++banks2SF = '+banks2SF);
        banks = banks2SF.split('\\,');
        system.debug('++++banks.size() = '+banks.size());
        //Check for proper assignment
        if(banks.size()>0){
            for(Integer i=0;i<banks.size();i++){
                 system.debug('+++++banks['+i+']='+banks[i]);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks @SarojBera, already test it and it's perfect ! but i just know that multi-select picklist can be grouped in report. any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Solution

**Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MutiselectPicklistTest">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
        <input type="button" onclick="checkselected();" value="click" class="btn"/>
        <script>
        function checkselected(){
          var x=document.getElementById("selectId");
          var selectOptions = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
             if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
                  selectOptions.push(x.options[i].value);
              }
          }
          console.log(selectOptions);
          submitAF(JSON.stringify(selectOptions));
        }
        </script>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!Submit}" name="submitAF" rerender="op">
            <apex:param name="selectArray" value="" assignTo="{!banks2SF}" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <apex:outputPanel id="op">
           <select id="selectId" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="Standard Chartered;" >Standard Chartered</option> 
                <option value="ANZ;">ANZ</option> 
                <option value="DBS;">DBS</option> 
                <option value="UOB;">UOB</option> 
            </select>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

on click of button first call Javacsript function to get All the selected option. And add all the selected values into javascript array i.e. `selectOptions`
Now call action function and pass the selected option(Using `JSON.stringify` this will convert the array into JSON string)  `submitAF(JSON.stringify(selectOptions));`

Action function assign that string to `banks2SF`.  now you can access that string into controller.

---

**Class**

```
public class MutiselectPicklistTest {
    public String banks2SF{get;set;}
    public PageReference Submit(){
    system.debug('========banks2SF======='+banks2SF);

    List<String> lst = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(banks2SF, List<String>.class);

    system.debug('=======lst====='+lst);
    return null;
    }
}
```

You may need to deserlize the JSON string i.e. banks2SF to get all the list string

Comment: Thanks @Ratan, i try using your code but somehow i get null input to JSON parser error. but when i saw in debug log, your lst get all the values. did i do it wrong ?

Comment: @FebrianTarigan Can you just create a new VF page and class with my above code and try. check it is working or not. ? The reason I am saying I have tested this. Reason can be with your existing code. If above saroj code is working then defiantly it should work .. I think you may forgot to use `<apex:param name="selectArray" value="" assignTo="{!banks2SF}" />` in actionFunction you can use this in apex:commandbutton

Answer (score 2):

You don't explain why you can't use `apex:selectList`. Using that would make for a cleaner (and easier to test) solution and you can still tweak the styling via the `style` and `styleClass` attributes:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!banks}" multiselect="true">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="Standard Chartered" itemLabel="Standard Chartered"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="ANZ" itemLabel="ANZ"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="DBS" itemLabel="DBS"/>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="UOB" itemLabel="UOB"/>
</apex:selectList>

public String[] banks{get;set;}
public PageReference Submit(){
    web2lead.List_of_Bank__c = String.join(banks, ';');
    update web2lead;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Keith, i can't use apex:selectList because it make my page look worse even i styling with styleClass. i already try using select list and i can get the value.  So i need do it with html select tag.

Comment: @FebrianTarigan OK. Personally I would persevere with the styling (e.g. try using [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)) for the sake of cleaner code.